# Displaying component within card in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to learn Angular 2, so I'm building a simple site that allows college students to track their grades.

I have two components, my main view component, and my "semester" component" which contains a table and some other things.

What I want to be able to do is press a button in my main view and have it create a new semester, and display it.

Here is my semester component:

```html
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {MatTable} from '@angular/material';
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'semester-',
    styleUrls: ['./Semester.css'],
    templateUrl: './Semester.html'
})
export class Semester {
    @ViewChild('courseTable') courseTable: MatTable<course>;
    courses: course[] = [];
    displayedColumns: string[] = ['courseNumber', 'courseName', 'grade', 'credits'];
    possibleGrades: string[] = ['A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B','B-','C+','C','C-','D+','D','D-','F','P','W' ];
    dataSource = this.courses;
    season: string;
    year: number;
    constructor() {
        this.season = 'Spring';
        this.year = 2018;
    }


    addCourse() {
        this.courses.push({courseID: '', courseName: 'Course Name', grade: 'A', credits: 0});
        this.courseTable.dataSource = this.courses;
        this.courseTable.renderRows();
    }
}

export interface course {
    courseID: string;
    courseName: string;
    grade: string;
    credits: number;
}
```

Here is my main.html

```html
<h1 id="mainHeader">College Crammer</h1>
    <mat-sidenav-container style="background-color: darkgray; border-radius: 10px;">
      <mat-sidenav-content>
        <mat-card id="masterCard">
          <h1>Add Some Data</h1>
    
          <div *ngFor="let semester of semesters">{{semester}}</div>
          <button mat-raised-button matTooltip="Add another semester to your plan" (click)="addSemester()">Add another semester</button>
        </mat-card>
      </mat-sidenav-content>
      <mat-sidenav>
        <mat-card id="sideCard">
          <h1>This is my sidebar</h1>
        </mat-card>
      </mat-sidenav>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
```

This "works", in the sense that when I press the button it puts out [object Object]. I need it to display the HTML within the template of the semester object, as though I typed .

Any help would be appreciated, I am really new to Angular (just started today), and I scoured the documentation but didn't find anything  that seemed to help.

Comment: check this https://jaxenter.com/dynamically-create-component-angular-142720.html